# Next/Previous Record (Database Android)

Tags: android, sqlite

[image]

I have some records in SQLite Database. With more than 2 records. I want to go to for example

- id:1 to id:2 when press next and

  - id:2 to id:1 when press previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the next record (if any):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE id > :PreviousValue
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

For the previous record, use `<` and `DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define an integer id and update it when the user press next or previous and then update the screen based on the updated id.

You can read all records and store them on in a list and when you want to update screen, you can access selected record by calling `list.get(id)`.

If you don't want to store all records in a list simply select a record from database where its id is equal to id.

Comment: what about missing records? for example 1,2,3,5,6 . 4 got deleted . Ah I think I got an idea. Thanks . Let me try

Comment: If you don't have large data store all of them in a list. So you wouldn't concern about database changes.